# How do I add more information about APIs in Swagger?

Tags: java, javadoc, swagger, api-doc

I included `swagger-springmvc` in my project and managed to get the Swagger UI working, but right now there's very little information about the APIs in the UI. All I see is information extracted through reflection.

This is what a controller method looks like:

```
/**
 * Read all users matching given filter
 * @param String filter The text by which to filter the usernames
 * @return User[] Array of users matching given filter
 * @throws Exception
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{filter}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
Collection<User> getUsers(@PathVariable("filter") String filter) throws Exception {
    return domain.getUsersFilteredBy(filter);
}
```

And on the right side of each method Swagger documents the method's name, in this case:

```
get Users
```

but I was expecting to see this:

```
Read all users matching given filter
```

In the example on helloreverb.com, I see the description of each of those methods. How can I get swagger to add the descriptions of my controller methods to the UI like so?

[image: Swagger documentation example]

Answer (score 5):

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Read all users matching given filter",  notes = "Will get all the users for the given filter")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use @Operation from package io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations;

```
@GetMapping
@Operation(summary = "My Summary", description = "My Description")
public Object getSomeObject(){..}
```